# Comparing array elements

Tags: c, arrays

Can you help me what's wrong with this, everytime i input 1, nothing happens. i need to compare a single element of the string which i am getting to 1 but i could not do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

main()
{

    int k,;
    char x[10],array[10];
    array[0]='X';
    array[1]='C';
    array[2]='O';
    array[3]='M';
    array[4]='P';
    array[5]='U';
    array[6]='T';
    array[7]='E';
    array[8]='R';
    array[9]='S';

    gets(x);

    if(x[0]==1)
        printf("%c",array[1]);

    getch();
}
```

Comment: Huh? The ascii character with ordinal `1` is not at *all* the same as the character `1`.

Comment: ...also, the problem has nothing at all to do with arrays. It would be helpful to modify it to be more representative of the actual cause -- otherwise, it's unlikely that people having the same problem (but not happening to misdiagnose it in the same way) would be able to find this question.

Comment: You should really format your code. The way you're doing it now is pretty bad. Also, the `main` without a return type and the `int k,;` shouldn't let your code compile at all.

Comment: those are just for experiments i'm trying to use that in a for loop.

Answer (score 3):

If you're entering `1` as input, then you need to check for the **character** 1, not the **ordinal** `1`.

Thus:

```
if (x[0] == '1')
```

not

```
if (x[0] == 1)
```

Comment: i see thanks, but why want i seem to use that here: gets(x);

for(k=1;k<=9;k++)
{
if(x[0]== 'k')
printf("%c",array[k]);
}

Comment: @user3259739 I don't understand your follow-up question. Could you try to improve the grammar?

Comment: im trying to use the code in a for loop but nothing appears.

Comment: @user3259739, see http://ideone.com/27Fw4I. That said, this is really a separate question, and should be asked that way.

Comment: ahhh it doesn't work on my compiler, still nothing appears after i input a number for x :(

Comment: @user3259739 Question. In your original question, what did you expect would happen if the user typed `300` into the `gets`? Would `x[0]` have become 300?

Comment: hey @CharlesDuffy it already worked. :) although i had to alter the code.